# How to store specified data for each user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Good day. I need to store specified data for each user. So, i have read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
  <profile>
    <properties>
      <add name="ChosenItems" />
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

So, when i try to set ChosenItems property value in controller i get an error. What's wrong?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Profile.ChosenItems = "smtng";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Error that i've got:
error CS1061: 'ProfileBase' does not contain a definition for 'ChosenItems' and no extension method 'ChosenItems' accepting a first argument of type 'ProfileBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

From the Microsoft article:
When your application runs, ASP.NET creates a ProfileCommon class, which is a dynamically generated class that inherits the ProfileBase class.

So, if i'm correct understand this, i need get ChosenItems property from ProfileCommon. But how?

Comment: If I remember correctly, MVC handles profile a little differently. Check this out: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667595/Profile-Provider-in-Asp-Net-MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667595/Profile-Provider-in-Asp-Net-MVC), it gives an overview of how to implement the profile object with your fields.

Comment: @c1phr it might works, but how connectionString looks that i should to use? I tried to use connectionStrings that placed below, but i had errors
  
 An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ..\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\App_Data\mydb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @c1phr
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyDbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="Task5And6.Source.UserProfile">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MyDbConnection" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
  </system.web>